# How to set camera live feed as wallpaper in android

Tags: java, android, camera, transparent, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make an android application which sets the camera's live feed as wallpaper. I am almost done with the coding part. The thing is when i click the set wallpaper button, the live wallpaper chooser menu opens. But as soon as i select my app in it, the application crashes. I know its kinda existing app, but its a clients demand.

**WelcomeActivity.java**

```
 package com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton imgButt;

    public WelcomeActivity()
    {
    }
     protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imgButt=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.setButton);
            imgButt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                    {
                        intent.setAction("android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER");
                        intent.putExtra("android.service.wallpaper.extra.LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT", new ComponentName("com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera", "com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera.TransparentWallpaperService"));
                    } else

                        intent.setAction("android.service.wallpaper.LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER");
                        intent.putExtra("android.service.wallpaper.extra.LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT", new ComponentName("com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera", "com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera.TransparentWallpaperService"));
                    //}
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }


}
```

**TransparentWallpaperService.java:**

```
package com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera;

import com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera.GenericaCamera;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class TransparentWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    private class MyWallpaperEngine extends android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine
    {

        GenericaCamera GC;
        final TransparentWallpaperService this$0;

        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder)
        {
            if (GC == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (TransparentWallpaperService.existing != null)
                    {
                        TransparentWallpaperService.existing.destroyExisting();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception) { }
                GC = new GenericaCamera(surfaceholder, getBaseContext());
                TransparentWallpaperService.existing = GC;
            }
            super.onCreate(surfaceholder);
        }

        private MyWallpaperEngine()
        {

            super();
            this$0 = TransparentWallpaperService.this;
        }

        MyWallpaperEngine(MyWallpaperEngine mywallpaperengine)
        {
            this();
        }
    }


    public static GenericaCamera existing;

    public TransparentWallpaperService()
    {
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService.Engine onCreateEngine()
    {
        return new MyWallpaperEngine(null);
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**GenricaCamera.java:**

```
package com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera;

import java.util.Iterator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GenericaCamera implements android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static boolean isPreviewRunning = false;
    private Camera cameraDevice;
    private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder;
    private Context context;

    public GenericaCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, Context context1)
    {
        cameraDevice = null;
        cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
        context = context1;
        cameraSurfaceHolder = surfaceholder;
        cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(3);
        cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    private static android.hardware.Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int i, int j, android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters)
    {
        android.hardware.Camera.Size size = null;
        Iterator iterator = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes().iterator();
        do
        {
            android.hardware.Camera.Size size1;
            do
            {
                if (!iterator.hasNext())
                {
                    return size;
                }
                size1 = (android.hardware.Camera.Size)iterator.next();
            } while (size1.width > i || size1.height > j);
            if (size == null)
            {
                size = size1;
            } else
            {
                int k = size.width * size.height;
                if (size1.width * size1.height > k)
                {
                    size = size1;
                }
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    public void destroyExisting()
    {
        if (cameraDevice != null)
        {
            cameraDevice.stopPreview();
            cameraDevice.setPreviewCallback(null);
            cameraDevice.release();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        isPreviewRunning = false;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k)
    {
        if (cameraDevice != null)
        {
            if (isPreviewRunning)
            {
                cameraDevice.stopPreview();
            }
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = cameraDevice.getParameters();
            android.hardware.Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(j, k, parameters);
            if (size != null)
            {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            }
            cameraDevice.setParameters(parameters);
            cameraDevice.startPreview();
            isPreviewRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cameraDevice == null)
            {
                cameraDevice = Camera.open();
                cameraDevice.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                cameraDevice.setPreviewDisplay(cameraSurfaceHolder);
            }
            cameraDevice.startPreview();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create preview!", 1).show();
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder)
    {
        if (cameraDevice == null)
        {
            return;
        } else
        {
            destroyExisting();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.wallpaper.transparenthighdefcamera.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".services.TransparentCameraHelperService" />
        <service android:name=".services.TransparentWallpaperService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did u resolved ur problem?